# Error using community.aws.redshift module with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-awx

I am trying to write a playbook that takes will start/stop a redshift instance. I was able to achieve the same for an RDS instance like:

```
    - name: start ec2
      amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
        state: running
        instance_ids:
          - i-029e7bf31c0cd39d8
```

How do I achieve the same for a redshift instance. I am trying something like this:

```
    - name: start redshift
      community.aws.redshift:
        id: myinstance-redshift
        state: started
        command: modify
```

Ansible tower throws the following error

> SSH password:
> ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.aws.redshift'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
> The error appears to be in '/runner/project/playbooks/getversions.yml': line 23, column 7, but may
> be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
> The offending line appears to be:
> - name: start redshift
> ^ here

I believe I have the necessary modules installed. Here is the output of *ansible-galaxy collection list*
[image]

Here is the version details:
[image]

The output of *ansible-doc community.aws.redshift* command looks like this:

```
>COMMUNITY.AWS.REDSHIFT    (/home/ec2-user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/reds>

        Creates, deletes, or modifies Amazon Redshift cluster instances.

ADDED IN: version 1.0.0 of community.aws

OPTIONS (= is mandatory):

- access_key
        AWS access key ID.
        See the AWS documentation for more information about access tokens
        https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-
        secret-access-keys.
        The `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', `AWS_ACCESS_KEY' or `EC2_ACCESS_KEY' environment variables may
        also be used in decreasing order of preference.
        The `aws_access_key' and `profile' options are mutually exclusive.
        The `aws_access_key_id' alias was added in release 5.1.0 for consistency with the AWS
        botocore SDK.
        The `ec2_access_key' alias has been deprecated and will be removed in a release after
        2024-12-01.
        Support for the `EC2_ACCESS_KEY' environment variable has been deprecated and will be
        removed in a release after 2024-12-01.
        aliases: [aws_access_key_id, aws_access_key, ec2_access_key]
        default: null
        type: str

- allow_version_upgrade
        When `allow_version_upgrade=true' the cluster may be automatically upgraded during the
        maintenance window.
        aliases: [version_upgrade]
        default: true
        type: bool
```

and this goes on describing each parameter, which I have cut short here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Smells like an installation snafu, not a programming problem; what does `ansible-doc community.aws.redshift` output? Please don't put it in the comments, instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75531795/edit) and include those details

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel. I have edited my question and added the output of the ansible-doc command.

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty mysterious. It almost seems like `ansible-doc` is one install but you're using a different `ansible-playbook` than you think you are. Have you tried running that playbook at higher verbosity (`ansible-playbook -vvvv`) to see if it helps track down the misalignment?

Comment: Also, while I doubt very seriously it's the root problem, the parameter is not `id:` but rather [`identifier:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/community/aws/redshift_module.html#parameter-identifier)

Comment: @mdaniel, I tried with higer verbosity. I still got the same error saying "Could not resolve module/action  'community.aws.redshift' ".  Do you think it would help if I uninstall the ansible and re-install a different version may be ?

Comment: Always a good idea to start fresh and see what assumption was violated, or if you can reproduce the issue

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel. I will try that and get back here.